# How bind Python class with record's form on Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I'm creating a new view to user create a record of a object inside a module, so I've created the `<record>` on `.xml` and a class python on `.py` file to bind the fields' `<record>` with python variables. Problem is that when I run the erros occurs:

```
Model not found: new.activity.type

Error context:
View `New Activity Type`
[view_id: 771, xml_id: vz_custom_activities.custom_activities_new_activity_type, model: new.activity.type, parent_id: n/a]
None" while parsing /Users/augustosansoncadini/odoo_dev/git/addons/vz_custom_activities/views/views.xml:35, near
<record id="custom_activities_new_activity_type" model="ir.ui.view">
      <field name="name">New Activity Type</field>
      <field name="model">new.activity.type</field>
      <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
          <group>
            <field name="name"/>
          </group>
        </form>
      </field>
    </record>
```

***views.xml***

```
<record id="custom_activities_new_activity_type" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">New Activity Type</field>
  <field name="model">new.activity.type</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
      <group>
        <field name="name"/>
      </group>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

***new_activity_type.py***

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class new_activity_type(models.Model):
    _name = 'new.activity.type'

    name = fields.Text('Name')
```

***__init__.py***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import controllers
from . import models
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported your `models` directory with relative path, which is okay, but you also need to remember python modules (`.py` files) inside your `models` have to be imported in the models directory `__init__.py` file using relative path. That way, whenever your module is installed in odoo, odoo will import the modules root directory `__init__.py`, all of the `models` definition in the `.py` files will get imported.

This is not just for models directory but any other directories also, you have to import `.py` to get those python codes working. For example, `controllers`, `wizards`, `reports` directory `.py` files also, if there are any. This works in following way: whenever a package in Python gets imported, `__init.py__` files get executed automatically, so the execution goes like following:

> addons root dir `__init__.py` >> models dir `__init__.py` >> all `.py`
>   files that are imported in that file.

In your `models` directory, create `__init__.py` file, if not already exists.

***models/__init__.py***

```
from . import new_activity_type
```

Comment: I did it, but the fields showed on the view aren't same that declared on `new_activity_type.py` instead show fields declared on `models.py`

Comment: can you share your `__init__.py` file code and your view screenshot?

Comment: view: https://imgur.com/a/c2fXay5, init.py: https://imgur.com/a/hJ6ySdf

Comment: I see you also imported your `models.py` file, is that same model `new.activity.type` also defined in that file, or something else?

Comment: i just added my new_activity_type .py file, all other things was added automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190387/discussion-between-arryph-and-augusto).

Comment: Guys please update the question, the answer makes no sense with the provided information in it...

Comment: Have in mind that StackOverflow is for other users, too. :-)

Comment: the problem is `new.activity.type` model not found, which can occur for many situation including if model definition is not imported, why the answer is not making any sense to you?